# How to convert a binary representation of a string into byte in Java?

Tags: java, string, binary, byte

as the title says, how do I do it? Its easy to convert from string -> byte -> string binary, But how do I convert back? Below is a example.
The output is :
'f' to binary: 01100110 
294984

I read somewhere that I could use the Integer.parseInt but clearly that is not the case :( Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
 :)

```
public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         String s = "f";
          byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
          StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
          for (byte b : bytes)
          {
             int val = b;
             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
             {
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                val <<= 1;
             }
             binary.append(' ');
          }
          System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);

        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("01100110", 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You desperately need to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`Byte.parseByte()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a radix of 2:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(str, 2);
```

---

Using your example:

```
System.out.println(Byte.parseByte("01100110", 2));
```

```
102
```

Comment: Except that the OP (if he is to be believed) wants to convert *to* binary text string.

Comment: (Though on re-reading, it's impossible to tell *what* the OP wants.)

Comment: That doesn't work for values greater than `01111111` == `127` as Byte has a range from -128 to 127.

Comment: @thomas.mc.work Right but the OP just wants bytes; reread the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it to an integer in base 2, and convert to a byte array. 
In your example you've got 16 bits you can also use short.

```
short a = Short.parseShort(b, 2);
ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(a);

byte[] array = bytes.array();
```

Just in case if you need it for a `Very Big String.`

```
String b = "0110100001101001";
byte[] bval = new BigInteger(b, 2).toByteArray();
```

Comment: Except that the OP (if he is to be believed) wants to convert *to* binary text string.

Answer (score 0):

I made like this, converted a string s -> byte[] and then used Integer.toBinaryString to get binaryStringRep. I converted bianryStringRep by using Byte.parseByte to get the bianryStringRep  into byte and the String(newByte[]) to get the byte[] into a String! Hope it helps others then me aswell! ^^

```
public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

         String s = "foo";
          byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
          byte[] newBytes = new byte[s.getBytes().length];
          for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
              String binaryStringRep = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
              byte newByte = Byte.parseByte(binaryStringRep, 2);
              newBytes[i] = newByte;
          }

        String str = new String(newBytes, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```